# Show equivalence of statement $\left(P\rightarrow Q\right) \wedge \left(Q\rightarrow R\right)$ to ...

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Show that $\left(P\rightarrow Q\right) \wedge \left(Q\rightarrow R\right)$ is equivalent to $\left(P\rightarrow R\right) \wedge \left[\left(P\leftrightarrow Q\right) \vee \left(R\leftrightarrow Q\right)\right]$

After one page of expanding and collapsing the right hand side, I get as a result 
$$
\left(P\rightarrow Q\right) \wedge \left(Q\rightarrow P\right) \wedge \left(P\rightarrow R\right)
$$

Can anybody help? Although this question has been marked as a duplicate, the linked page only provides a partial answer (one direction) and the other answer is in Polish notation which I am not familiar with.

Comment: Have you tried using a truth table?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I did not, but I think the challenge of the problem is to do it without the truth table, as I already know that it should be true (hopefully).

Comment: How do you expect to get a good answer without telling us all the constraints of the problem? What can we use?

Comment: @Dominik: take the hint and create a truth table! They provide insight that might help you realize how to proceed

Comment: Guess you are asking for a syntactic proof..what rules are you allowed to use?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: This is a textbook problem on introductory logic and there are no contraints stated.

Comment: @Saphrosit: DeMorgan's laws, associative laws, commutative laws, absorption laws, tautology laws, contradiction laws, conditional laws, contrapositive law

Comment: If you want to do it syntactically, try writing both in terms of and, or, and not and then using laws for those. (Also, as an aside, any truth table proof should be able to be converted, perhaps at some length, to a syntactic proof.)

Comment: @Dominik I posted your question from yesterday [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159455/showing-p-to-q-land-q-to-r-equiv-p-to-r-landp-leftrightarrow-q-lor-r). You may want to see it for a full solution--Tunococ's answer is quite nice.